# probeGC crash in Fabric Crashlytics

Tags: ios, crash, crashlytics, xcode11, google-fabric

This crash is happening only on iOS 13.3.1 on iPad 6 & iPad Pro (12.9 inch, 3rd Gen)

This crash is happening randomly and is a real deterrent to my customers.

```
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1b80c4090 objc_msgSend + 16
1  Foundation                     0x1b875c4f0 probeGC + 120
2  Foundation                     0x1b8672d64 -[NSConcreteMapTable rehashAround:] + 204
3  Foundation                     0x1b8672c68 -[NSConcreteMapTable removeObjectForKey:] + 248
4  UIKitCore                      0x1bc8c3484 _UIAnalyticsGatherMultitouchAnalytics + 632
5  UIKitCore                      0x1bc43ea10 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 204
6  Instabug                       0x103980274 __IBGSwizzle_sendEvent + 240
7  UIKitCore                      0x1bc4b6c20 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 5880
8  UIKitCore                      0x1bc4b917c __handleEventQueueInternal + 4924
9  UIKitCore                      0x1bc4b1ff0 __handleHIDEventFetcherDrain + 108
10 CoreFoundation                 0x1b831ea00 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
11 CoreFoundation                 0x1b831e958 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 80
12 CoreFoundation                 0x1b831e0f0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 180
13 CoreFoundation                 0x1b831923c __CFRunLoopRun + 1080
14 CoreFoundation                 0x1b8318adc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464
15 GraphicsServices               0x1c22b9328 GSEventRunModal + 104
16 UIKitCore                      0x1bc42663c UIApplicationMain + 1936
17 DocOn                          0x100df8e10 main + 15 (main.m:15)
18 libdyld.dylib                  0x1b81a2360 start + 4
```

Comment: Try updating fabric  library to lastest version.